# Html page getting weird with doctype

Tags: html, doctype

I wrote an html page, with some css in a separate file and it worked fine. Then i realized that i should add a doctype declaration to my html. I did that and my page was completely messed up! I tried all types of declarations but all ended up the same!!!

This is my html (currently only working with Chrome, and without doctype):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>Luca Rood - Home</title>
    </head>
    <body background="images\background.jpg">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="header-back"></div>
            <div id="top-spacing"></div>
            <div id="content">
                <a href="index.html" title="Luca Rood - Home">
                    <img id="image" src="images\logo.png" alt="Luca Rood">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my css:

```
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }

#header {
    position: relative;
    height: 15%;
    }

#header-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000000;
    opacity: 0.3;
    z-index:1;
    }

#top-spacing {
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    }

#content {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    height: 60%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index:2;
    }

#image {
    height: 100%;
    }
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance,

Luca

Comment: How is it "messed up"?

Comment: What `doctype` did you "add"? Why didn't you submit that instead of the CSS?

Comment: If you choose to use a doctype (which you should) you'll have to live with the browser following this doctype. With a doctype you tell the browser to behave in a certain way. In theory all browsers should behave the same, so that's more or less why you should pick a doctype. So you will have to decide which doctype you want to use and change your css afterwards. If you don't pick a doctype, the browser renders the page in "quirks" mode and you don't want this to happen (even if at the moment your page looks best in it).

Comment: I user version 4.01 Transitional, but tested with a bunch of others.

Comment: There is no need for a bunch of doctypes. Use HTML5 doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: If you are having problems with the background image, it is because it is deprecated

Comment: also your image `src` paths have back slashes instead of forward slashes in them

Comment: I just tested this, and the problem seems to be that `#image` gets way bigger with the doctype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having the classic percentage heights problem. To fix it, you must add `height:100%` to the `body` style and add an style on the `html` element that has `height:100%` as well:

```
<style>
    body{
        /*...*/
        height:100%;
    }
    html{
        height:100%;
    }
</style>
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score -1):

Try this above < html > tag

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: this is exactly the problem. The asker clearly said that he/she tried many doctypes and they didn't work.